# Parallel transport on Riemannian symmetric spaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

What would be a reference for the following property of symmetric spaces?

Given a smooth curve $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow M$ on a symmetric space $(M,g)$, there exists an isometry $\varphi : M \rightarrow M$ taking $\gamma(0)$ to $\gamma(1)$ and such that the parallel transport map 
$$
P_\gamma : T_{\gamma(0)}M \longrightarrow  T_{\gamma(1)}M 
$$
equals the differential of $\varphi$ at the point $\gamma(0)$.

I guess one can get this from two particular cases: (1) the curve $\gamma$ is closed and we are looking at holonomy vs. isotropy groups, and (2) the curve $\gamma$ is a geodesic segment and is the projection of a translation of one-parameter subgroup of isometries, but I would love just to be able to cite something.

I looked up in Helgason and it does not seem to be there, at least in this guise.

Comment: I would try Eberlein's book, though it might only cover non-positively curved symmetric spaces.

Comment: Looking at closed curves, my guess would be that this property is equivalent to $M$ being a rank one space.

Comment: @Antonius, no, the holonomy group at a point $p \in M$ is contained in the isotropy subgroup of the point for all symmetric spaces.

Comment: I know that you do not want a proof, but here is one :) --- take even number of evenly spaces points on your curve and compose their central symmetries --- you get an approximation for the parallel translation --- pass to the limit.

Comment: Yes, that's basically the proof you get if  you look under the hood of the holonomy-isotropy result: use the result for geodesics  by approximating general curves by broken geodesics. I just have paper-writing fatigue and would like to \cite this away.

Comment: Can you comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2354979/72694) if you get a chance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for the reference see Kobayashi-Nomizu Vol I page 262 Corollary 7.6.

Besides Petrunin's well-known argument the claim is also an obvious corollary of Cartan's Theorem 2.1 page 157 of Do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry"